# How we can authenticate webview with username and password in xamarin.forms for iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I recently started development using Xamarin. Forms and I am new to C#. I have a URL which I am using for resetting password, this URL is an HTML page and I am loading it in a Webview. If we open this URL in a browser it will ask for authentication i.e Username and Password, but I am not able to open this on iOS.
I have created custom class for Webview in Android and iOS. For Android it's working fine but in iOS it's not.

Code:

```
private void WillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge
(NSUrlConnection connection, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge)
```

But I am not sure how to use this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the newer iOS webkit WkWebView, you can override the function DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge in your WKNavigationDelegate. Like so:

```
public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate 
{
     public override void DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(WKWebView webView, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<nsurlsessionauthchallengedisposition, nsurlcredential=""> completionHandler) 
     {
         var credential = new NSUrlCredential("username", "password", NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession);
         completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, credential);
     }
}
```